# Return int from for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to get the number of patients in the front of a specific one. How can I return int from a for loop? It returns 0 all the time.

```
public int pAhead(String name) {
        Patient p;
        int patientsAhead = 0;
        for(int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
          p = list.get(i); //get each object from array
          String n = p.getName();
          if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(n))
          {
              //if name passed is equal to object getName, than get the index of that object
              patientsAhead = list.indexOf(p); 
          }
        }
        return patientsAhead;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure 0 is the wrong result?

Comment: where do you have `list` declared ? Cause it isn't passed to function in code u posted

Comment: Change the true part of the if statement to `return i;`.

Comment: @4rlekin it may be declared as global

Comment: it may (which also may be wrong design solution) but does it ?

Comment: as pointed out by @popovitsj `0` is returned because you're looking for a person who is not in that list... (is your list empty? do you ask for a name of a person not in the list? **do you have leading/trailing blanks in the name?**)

Comment: For testing you might like to try adding `System.out.println("[" + name + "] = [" + p.getName() + "]");` to your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was in a hurry and forgot to pass the objects into the array.

Comment: But now in GUI it shows java.lang.NullPointerException. It works with no GUI but with gui it doesn't.  int num = q.pAhead(p.getName());
        tArea.append("There are " + num + " patients ahead");

Answer (score 2):

First you dont need `list.indexOf(p);` because you already have the loop variable `i`

to return it just do

```
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(n)) {
    return i;
}
```

Note that [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) may result in something else depending on how you have implemented `equals` and you are are comparing with the name of the Person.

All that beeing said, make sure your list actually contains some elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return the value of i. It will give you the value which is matched with the passed name.

```
public int pAhead(String name) {

    Patient p;
    int patientsAhead = 0;
    for(int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
      p = list.get(i); //get each object from array
      String n = p.getName();
      if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(n))
      {
          //if name passed is equal to object getName, than increase your counter 
          patientsAhead = i;  
      }
    }
    return patientsAhead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do if I understand your question is to add a break statement when you see the number you are interested for.

So :

```
public int pAhead(String name) {
        Patient p;
        int patientsAhead = 0;
        for(int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
          p = list.get(i); //get each object from array
          String n = p.getName();
          if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(n))
          {
              //if name passed is equal to object getName, than increase your counter 
              patientsAhead = i;
              break;
          }
        }
        return list.size() - patientsAhead;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes the `list` variable is a list that contains patients and the number that you want, patients ahead of a patient, is the index of the patient you're looking for.

If you have the `Patient` object that you want to lookup, just doing `pAhead = list.indexOf(patient)` should give you the same result without using a `for` loop. Just make sure you check if the result is negative, then it means the patient you're looking for is not in the list.

This solutions depends on having the `Person.equal()` method defined. Some IDEs can generate it for you.

If you either don't have the object or you can't (or don't want to) change the `equal()` method, you can loop just as you did and `return i` inside the loop, like other answers suggest:

```
for (int i=0; i<=list.size(); i++) {
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i).getName())) {
        return i;
    }
}
```